# What's the ODBC SparkSQL Source Format for Connecting with PHP ODBC & Spark?

Tags: php, sql, odbc

What's the ODBC SparkSQL Source Format for Connecting with PHP ODBC & Spark?

Here's the code I need to edit:

`$conn = odbc_pconnect("CData ODBC SparkSQL Source","user","password");`

What's the format for the field: "CData ODBC SparkSQL Source"?